# Importing Data to neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import a Database on Game of Thrones for neo4j.

[Github_link_to_the_data](https://github.com/bladow/GoTGraphGist/blob/master/GoTCreate.cql)

I copied and pasted the code to my cypher browser but I keep getting errors.
Can someone please instruct me how to import this data so I can start querying this database?

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input ')': expected 
whitespace,
 comment or an expression (line 630, column 3 (offset: 24452))
"CREATE (banner)-[:BANNERMAN_OF]->(euron);"
```

I would appreciate some help here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Neo4j Browser has only recently been augmented with the ability to process multiple cypher statements in the query editor (separated by `;`), and there are still a couple bugs being worked out here as of 3.4.5.

Your best bet for processing these is via cypher-shell, you can pipe in the input file and it will take care of the rest.

Check out [this section of the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell-syntax), and pay attention to example 10.17 on how to pipe the input file.